# Splitting a String after every nth element php

Tags: php

I have a string in this form

```
$navigation="<li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li>";
```

The list is generated dynamically from database and hence the number of elements is not fixed. I want to split this list after every 5th element, so if there are 10 `"<li></li>"` elements in this string I should get two strings output1 and output2.

I have tried explode but it doesn't work as we have to impose restriction on nth element and I have also tried string_split but that is not working also.

So what is the solution?

Ahmar

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$s = "<li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li>";
if (preg_match_all('~((?:<li>.*?</li>){5})~i', $s, $arr))
   print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>A</li><li>B</li>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li><li>A</li><li>B</li>
        )

)
```